# How to pass data from MainActivity to Recyclerview adapter in KOTLIN ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I tried accessing `shared preferences` inside `view holder` but I want to access it throughout the whole activity which I couldn’t so then I tried to pass the values from `MainActivity` through `intent.putextras()` but I don’t know how to receive it inside the recycler view adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem today while creating an app. I searched the problem but didn't got any solution. Then I solved it by my own method as stated below.

In your **MainActivity.kt**, create a public function which returns the values that you want to receive in your Adapter class. I created a function **getData()** with a return type of HashMap in case you want to pass more than 1 values to adapter class.

```
fun getData(): HashMap<String, String> {
    val map = HashMap<String, String>()
    map["Data1"] = "Hello this is data 1"
    map["Data2"] = "Hello this is data 2"

    return map
}
```

Now, go to your **adapter** **class** and inside your **onBindViewHolder** function, call the function created in **MainActivity.kt** as shown below:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name)
    val description: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, model: Modal) {
    val activity: MainActivity? = holder.itemView.context as MainActivity
    val map = activity?.getData()
    val data = map?.get("Data1")
    Log.d("DataFromMainActivity", data.toString())
}
```